# Is there a tool to load test a PLSQL

Tags: performance, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I know of utplsql for unit testing, is there a way I could use this in a loop to load test my stored procedure?

I dont want to use JMeter or go through any JDBC drivers - just trying to analyze the performance of the vanilla Stored Proc

Comment: There is an interesting article here: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_benchmark_testing.htm

Comment: What's wrong with JDBC? The overhead in calling the stored procedure should be negligible (compared to the runtime of the procedure)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: we already have some JDBC test results, we want to split further to DB only. Will enabling DEBUG on the Oracle driver help with actual times taken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think a unit test tool is the right approach, because you're not really making assertions about functionality.  With a load test you want to know how a procedure runs with a large volume of data, of if it's called lots of times.

So you might want to run it in a loop or against a big table and use a profiler to find bootlenecks.  If you're on 11g you should check out [the built-in hierarchical profiler](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_profiler.htm#ADFNS023).

Something like this:

```
begin
    DBMS_HPROF.START_PROFILING (
       location    => 'PROF_DATA_FILE_DIR'
       , filename    => 'HPROF_RUN1_20111109'
       );

    some_pkg.generate_lots_of_work(p_id => 1234);

    DBMS_HPROF.STOP_PROFILING;

end;
/
```

Or in a loop:

```
begin
    DBMS_HPROF.START_PROFILING (
       location    => 'PROF_DATA_FILE_DIR'
       , filename    => 'HPROF_RUN2_20111109'
       );

    for i in 1..1000
    loop
        some_pkg.do_this(p_num => i);
    end loop;

    DBMS_HPROF.STOP_PROFILING;

end;
/
```

Obviously, this won't help you in generating the gobs of data for load testing.  That's always the hardest part :)

Answer (score 0):

All of the classical vendor performance test tools, LoadRunner, Silk Performer, QALoad and Rational Performance Tester have direct to Database capability for executing performance tests on queries directly or against stored procedures.

The reason why these tools have this capability is because they generally existed in the market for a good half a decade when the standard for client=server was a two tier database thick client architecture.    Most of the stuff which has shown up in the market since 2000 is pretty much web only.