# Stored procedure performance comparison

Tags: performance, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Can someone suggest tools for comparing performance of oracle stored procedures on 11g.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a tool to load test a PLSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065419/is-there-a-tool-to-load-test-a-plsql)

Comment: Use the hierarchical profiler: see my answer to the question I referenced above

Answer (score 1):

**[Toad for Oracle](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-oracle/)** can do this for you, please see this as a [reference](http://oreilly.com/catalog/tdpr/chapter/excerpt.html)

Comment: That's for tuning SQL statements.  Stored procedures can have all sorts of other problems: for instance, if we are calling a query 10000 times instead of doing something set-based *once* it doesn't matter whether that SELECT is well tuned.

Comment: You're right.  I was thinking that he would test the query and then make it a PROC.

Comment: Some PL/SQL doesn't contain any SQL at all.  So I think tuning stored procedures is at least as much a developer task as a DBA one.

Comment: If you're a developer, you'd tune in TOAD.  If you're a DBA, you wouldn't.  When would a developer want to tune a stored procedure that had no SQL at all?

Comment: When it needs tuning.  Say if it's doing something computationally expensive.  Or doing lots of I/O.  Or waiting for a response from an extproc.  Or it is caching data in collections.  And so on.  Quite simply, there is more to tuning PL/SQL than merely tuning SQL statements.

Comment: And if it comes to it, there's more to tuning SQL statements than TOAD.  There are other (cheaper or free) IDEs.  There are command line (SQL PLus) tools, for when we cannot use a GUI.  And so on.